# How do I access this object in JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, weather

I'm trying to access the `weather` object in Javascript. I've tried `output.weather` but it returns `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

JSON:

```
[
   {
      "location":{
         "name":"XX",
         "zipcode":"XX",
         "lat":"42.284",
         "long":"-82.029",
         "timezone":"-4",
         "alert":"",
         "degreetype":"C",
         "imagerelativeurl":"http://blob.weather.microsoft.com/static/weather4/en-us/"
      },
      "current":{
         "temperature":"2",
         "skycode":"31",
         "skytext":"Clear",
         "date":"2020-04-03",
         "observationtime":"23:45:00",
         "observationpoint":"N0P 1E0, ON",
         "feelslike":"1",
         "humidity":"84",
         "winddisplay":"6 km/h North",
         "day":"Friday",
         "shortday":"Fri",
         "windspeed":"6 km/h",
         "imageUrl":"http://blob.weather.microsoft.com/static/weather4/en-us/law/31.gif"
      },
      "forecast":[
         {
            "low":"2",
            "high":"9",
            "skycodeday":"31",
            "skytextday":"Clear",
            "date":"2020-04-03",
            "day":"Friday",
            "shortday":"Fri",
            "precip":"0"
         },
         {
            "low":"2",
            "high":"11",
            "skycodeday":"32",
            "skytextday":"Sunny",
            "date":"2020-04-04",
            "day":"Saturday",
            "shortday":"Sat",
            "precip":"60"
         },
         {
            "low":"0",
            "high":"8",
            "skycodeday":"30",
            "skytextday":"Partly Sunny",
            "date":"2020-04-05",
            "day":"Sunday",
            "shortday":"Sun",
            "precip":"60"
         },
         {
            "low":"5",
            "high":"11",
            "skycodeday":"30",
            "skytextday":"Partly Sunny",
            "date":"2020-04-06",
            "day":"Monday",
            "shortday":"Mon",
            "precip":"30"
         },
         {
            "low":"9",
            "high":"13",
            "skycodeday":"26",
            "skytextday":"Cloudy",
            "date":"2020-04-07",
            "day":"Tuesday",
            "shortday":"Tue",
            "precip":"80"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

JS CODE:

```js
const rl = require('readline-sync');
const weather = require('weather-js');

var zipCode = rl.question('Please enter your ZIP code: ').toLowerCase();
var output;

weather.find({search: zipCode, degreeType: 'F'}, function(err, result) {
    if (err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    }

    output = JSON.stringify(result);
    console.log(output.weather); // returns undefined
});
```

Comment: JSON.stringify doesn't do what you seem to think it does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify 
The `output` variable is just a string; you can't do anything with it except printing it.

Comment: JSON.stringify turns it into a string

Comment: `JSON.stringify` will turn JSON to string, just remove `JSON.stringify` function and do `console.log(output)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that *output* is a string, not an object. Did you mean JSON.parse()? That outputs an object from a string.

Comment: I tried JSON.parse(), but I got an error. `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: What is the value of result? Is it a string or object?

Answer (score 1):

According to `weather-js` [documentation](https://github.com/devfacet/weather), `result` is already an object, so all you have to do is access it:

```
weather.find({search: zipCode, degreeType: 'F'}, function(err, result) {
    console.log("Low: " + result[0].forecast[0].low);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't notice that!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to parse the string after JSON.stringify() because JSON stringify change the object to a string.

Ref: [JSON Stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), [JSON Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)